# Need help with selecting research papers for Cycler Trajectories

Tags: low-energy-transfer

I have been reading small articles on Cycler trajectories and have found it to be quite interesting. So, I was wanting to do some research work in this area and I need help in acquiring research papers for reading. Is there anyone who could point towards a few research papers, to begin with?

Comment: Hi Suraj, *step 1* would be for you to type "cycler" in the search window at the top of the page and read some of the cycler questions and answers here, and *step 2* would be to have a look at some of the papers linked in them. With over 9,500 questions now, there is quite a body of knowledge and experience here already (make sure to put "cycler" in quotes https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYLiw.png). If you find something interesting and would like to ask something more specific, feel free to ask more questions as well. That would be *step 4*.

Comment: Another thing you can try as *step 3* is to go to `scholar.google.com` and search for "orbital cycler" or your own choice of search terms.

Comment: Also, how do I get acquainted with math involved in these papers? Is there any source for that?

Comment: I would say follow those four steps, find some math that you understand a little bit but need some clarification, and then ask a new question. In your new question, show the math, explain what you do understand, and ask a question about the part that you don't. Also have a look at all the answers to [Resources and references on the topic of space exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/12102) which is in the meta section of this site.